# make a good Json file to show in highchart

Tags: python, django-queryset

hello everyone I hope you are doing well, I want to do a chart to show the process for every office (like the rank of deliveries in every office per day) ,

**models.py**

```
class Evenement(models.Model):
EVENEMENT_CHOICES = (
    ("déposé","déposé"),
    ("reçu","reçu"),
    ("expédié","expédié"),
    ("affecté","affecté"),
    ("livré","livré"),
    ("echec de livraison","echec de livraison"),
)
mail_item_fid = models.ForeignKey(mail_item,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mail_item_fid_evenement')
from_office = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Evt_evenement')
date_Evt = models.DateTimeField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=EVENEMENT_CHOICES)
agent_delivery_cd = models.ForeignKey(Delivery_Agent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True ,related_name='agent_evenement')
def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {}, {}, {} '.format(self.mail_item_fid,self.from_office,self.date_Evt,self.status)
```

**views.py**

```
    @login_required
    def dataOfChart(request):
      dataset = Evenement.objects.annotate(Day=TruncDay('date_Evt')).values('Day','from_office')\
        .annotate(depot=Count('from_office',filter=Q(status='déposé')),
                affecte=Count('from_office',filter=Q(status='affecté')),
                livre=Count('from_office',filter=Q(status="livré")),
                taux=Cast(F('livre'), FloatField())/Cast(F('affecte'), FloatField())).all().order_by('from_office','Day')
      
      location_data = list(dataset)
      
      
      
      date = Evenement.objects.annotate(Day=TruncDay('date_Evt'))\
            .values_list('Day')\
            .annotate(count=Count('id'))\
            .values_list('Day')\
            .order_by('Day')\
            .filter(count__gt=1)
      datetime_list = list(date)

      return render(request, 'charts_event_list.html', {'location_data': location_data ,'datetime_list':json.dumps(datetime_list,sort_keys=True,indent=1,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)} )
```

**template.html**

```
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script>
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'deliveries rate per offices '
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: {%for Day in datetime_list %}{{Day|safe}}{%endfor %}
      },
      series: [
        {% for data in location_data %}
          {
              name: //here it should stock 'from_office' once,
              data: //here it should update the 'taux', 
              
          },

        {% endfor %}
          
          
    ]
  });
</script>
</body>
```

my json file **location_data** looks like this below ,

```
[
{
"from_office": 1, 
 "Day": "2020-06-19T00:00:00Z", 
 "taux": 1.0
}, 

{
"from_office": 1, 
"Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z",  
"taux": 1.0
}, 

{
"from_office": 2, 
"Day": "2020-06-19T00:00:00Z",  
"taux": 0.0
}, 
{
"from_office": 2, 
"Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z", 
"taux": 1.0
}, 
{
"from_office": 3, 
"Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z", 
"taux": 0.5
}
]
```

I want to achieve something like this so the highchart could read the name just once and update its data  =>

```
      series: [
      {
          name: 'office name 1 ',
          data: [0,0.25,1],    
      },
      {
          name: 'office name 2 ',
          data: [0,1,0.75],    
      },

]
```

Comment: first check what you get in HTML - save generated HTML in file and open in any text editor. And when you display it in browser you can use `DevTools` to see if there was no error, and if it load all needed JavaScript files.

Comment: why inside `{% for entry in data %}` you use another `{% for entry in data %}`  ? It makes no sense.

Comment: I want to show data for every office ... but I couldn't figure out how can I do it and what to change in my queryset, could you advice me in that please

Comment: maybe first create some data  manually to test how it should look with many offices. And when you generate HTML then you should check what you created in HTML - visit page in browser and save it in file to open in text editor - or use `Ctrl+U` to see source HTML. I think you created wrong data but you didn't even check what you created and you don't know what is the problem.

Comment: BTW: if you use `json.dumps()` in `{'data':json.dumps(data)}` then you send it as string and later `for entry in data` get char by char from this string - and you should see it if you check what you generated in HTML. You should send it normally `{'data': data}` to use it with  `for entry in data`

Comment: I did what you adviced me to do , I think I have issue in the for loop

Comment: Sir @furas can you see my update , I hope you can help me out

Comment: as for me in `views.py` you should group data to create list `series = [{"name": 'office name 1', "data": [0,0.25,1] }, ... ]` and send it to template. You can't group it in template because it need something more then only `for`-loop.

Comment: BTW: if you send to template  `json.dumps(datetime_list, ...)` then you can't use `{% for ...%}` because you send one string with all data, not list of data. With string you can do only `categories: {{ datetime_list }}` but it seems you want to format it in template so you should send it without using `json.dumps()` - and then you can use `{% for ... %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `views.py` you should group data to create list

```
series = [{"name": 'office name 1', "data": [0, 0.25, 1]}, ... ]
```

because it needs something more then only `for`-loop  and doing it in template can be big problem - if it is even possible.

Besides `views` is for (re)organizing data, and template is only for displaying it.

---

When you will have this list then you can send it with or without `json.dumps()`.

If you send to template without `json.dumps()`

```
render(request, 'charts_event_list.html', {'series': series, ... })
```

then use `for`-loop in template

```
series: [
    {% for item in series %}
      {
          name: {% item.name %}
          data: {% item.data %}
      },
    {% endfor %}
]
```

If you send with `json.dumps()` (which creates single string with all data)

```
render(request, 'charts_event_list.html', {'series': json.dumps(series), ... })
```

then put it directly in template

```
series: {{ series }}
```

---

And here example code which groups `taux`

```
import json

location_data = [
    {
        "from_office": 1, 
        "Day": "2020-06-19T00:00:00Z", 
        "taux": 1.0
    }, 
    {
        "from_office": 1, 
        "Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z",  
        "taux": 1.0
    }, 
    {
        "from_office": 2, 
        "Day": "2020-06-19T00:00:00Z",  
        "taux": 0.0
    }, 
    {
        "from_office": 2, 
        "Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z", 
        "taux": 1.0
    }, 
    {
        "from_office": 3, 
        "Day": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z", 
        "taux": 0.5
    }
]

series_dict = {}

for item in location_data:
    office = item['from_office']
    taux   = item['taux']
    if office not in series_dict:
        series_dict[office] = {
            'name': 'office name {}'.format(office),
            'data': []
        }
    series_dict[office]['data'].append(taux)                          

series = list(series_dict.values())

print('\n--- series as dict ---\n')       
print( series_dict )

print('\n--- series as list ---\n')       
print( series )

print('\n--- series as text ---\n')       
text = json.dumps(series)
print( text )
```

Result:

```
--- series as dict ---

{1: {'name': 'office name 1', 'data': [1.0, 1.0]}, 2: {'name': 'office name 2', 'data': [0.0, 1.0]}, 3: {'name': 'office name 3', 'data': [0.5]}}

--- series as list ---

[{'name': 'office name 1', 'data': [1.0, 1.0]}, {'name': 'office name 2', 'data': [0.0, 1.0]}, {'name': 'office name 3', 'data': [0.5]}]

--- series as text ---

[{"name": "office name 1", "data": [1.0, 1.0]}, {"name": "office name 2", "data": [0.0, 1.0]}, {"name": "office name 3", "data": [0.5]}]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Evenutally you can use `pandas` to group data

```
import pandas as pd

# convert dict to DataFrame (table)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(location_data)

# get only columns 'from_office', 'taux'
#df = df[ ['from_office', 'taux'] ]

# groups all data using values in column 'from_office'
groups = df.groupby('from_office')

# convert groups to list
series = [{
            'name': 'office name {}'.format(office),
            'data': values['taux'].to_list()
          } for office, values in groups]

print('\n--- pandas ---\n')
print(series)
```

Comment: thank you so much that what I was looking for really thank you, ... but I found an issue with the categories , like the office number 3 starts its data on 20 June not on 19 June, I don't know what should I do in that

Comment: do you have `19 June` for `office 3` in database ? It can be your problem. If you have it in database then you have to check why it doesn't get it - maybe you filtered it. If there is no `19 June` for `office 3` in database then you may have to insert some data in `location_data` for this value. You would have to get all dates `19 June`, `20 June` , etc and check for every date if there is taux for every office - if it is missing then you has to put some data in `location_data`. And this can be more complex problem.